# Does streaming inserts into bigquery have a limit, like per day only this much inserts are allowed?

Tags: google-bigquery, insert

```
client = bigquery.Client()
errors = client.insert_rows_json(table_id, que_list)
if errors == []:
    print("New rows have been added.")
else:
    print("Encountered errors while inserting rows: {}".format(errors))
```

This is my code for inserting data into a bigquery table, it works most of the time.
But sometimes it doesnt insert data into the table and no errors are shown

Answer (score 0):

See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts for more details on limits governing streaming inserts.

If you're getting ratelimit pushback from the service, you should see that manifest as error responses.  Based on the snippet you're likely using [google-cloud-bigquery](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/reference.html) python library, which does handle some level of retrying on your behalf.